# What is the rotation index of a figure 8?

Tags: differential-geometry, rotations, plane-curves, curves

Is it 0 since the total turning angle covers one clockwise circle and one counterclockwise circle thus making the total 0 and the rotation index 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you have a nice differentiable path (so that in fact you go around the two loops with opposite orientations).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, the context assumes it's smooth so that suffices, thank you